# Using xsltproc style sheet in java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I would like to convert an xml to a text with java. 
Until now i have used xsltproc with a style sheet file. Now i would like to do this inside a java class, and i would be very happy if i can do this reusing the style sheet of xsltproc. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java xslt tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968040/java-xslt-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the complete code for `Stylizer.java` here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/examples/jaxp/xslt/samples/Stylizer.java

this is exactly what i am looking for :)