# How to modify XML file according to a XML Schema (.xsd file)

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, wireshark

I have a xml file of network traffic exported by Wireshark. I need to develop a command line tool to parse the exported xml file, and create a new XML file according to given XML Schema (.xsd) or in other words modify a xml file according to given XML Schema.
Any ideas, how could I do that? most preferably in Java.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few technologies that you could use here. Often XML-to-XML translation is defined using some sort of intermediate language and then actual translation is wired together in a general purpose programming language, like Java.

Take a look at these:

- [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), [Java and XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968040/java-xslt-tutorial)
- [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/)

You can also do it in code, though I would adivise against this as it gets messy. However, for completeness, have a look at:

- [SAX](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)